# MySQL не понимает русские символы, вводимые через форму

Tags: php, mysql, кириллица

Добрый день!

Возникла проблема при переносе php-сайта с Денвера на удаленный сервер. Данные на русском языке, которые были занесены в базу заранее, выводятся корректно. Но когда я пытаюсь занести новые данные через форму, то в базу попадают знаки вопроса и они же выводятся на экран.

В базе тип таблиц MyISAM, сравнение utf8_general_ci.

В скрипте подключения к базе установлены SET NAMES utf8 и SET CHARACTER SET utf8.

На всех страницах сайта прописан header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8').

Что ещё нужно предпринять?

Comment: У полей таблицы, ествественно, тоже utf?

Comment: да, у полей тоже

Comment: А можно `Create Statement` для таблицы. Ну и код формы/страницы?

Comment: Стейтмента как такового нет - всё делалось через phpmyadmin, вручную. Форма самая банальная, с инпутами. Атрибуты - method="POST" action="usinfo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" (сюда код просто не копируется корректно)

Comment: В самой таблице новые данные корректные или тоже со знаками вопроса?

Comment: именно в самой таблице именно новые данные в виде знаков вопроса. старые отображаются и выводятся корректно

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, php файл, отправляющий данные, сохранен не в той кодировке? (нужна UTF-8)

Comment: Не, сохранено всё в UTF-8, не в этом дело ((

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, всем спасибо. Оказалось, что в скрипте подключения к базе данных надо ещё прописать SET COLLATION_CONNECTION="utf8_general_ci".